# how to incorporate the exit command in bash_profile alias?

Tags: bash, profile

On a remote box I use a command line alias "sleep" and the machine sleeps.

I would like to append some method of dropping back to the local machine to my alias like the following;

```
alias sleep="pmset sleepnow; exit"
```

or

```
alias sleep="pmset sleepnow; logout"
```

but those cause my shell to exit as soon as it starts up!

Comment: I can't understand the problem: `pmset sleepnow; exit` executes `pmset sleepnow` and then closes the shell. Isn't it *exactly* what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Heh heh, the answer came to me as I posted the question; do the logout first!

```
exit; pmset sleepnow
```

Comment: This way `pmset sleepnow` will never be executed